# Unified API / Groups

Tags: api, azure, office365

I am using the new Unified API to create groups in Office 365. Groups are getting created correctly, however there is one issue which I cannot find any documentation or explanation on.

How does the API handle mail enabled groups for Tenants with multiple domains?

E.g. I have my masterdomain.onmicrosoft.com which there are two domains in use domain1.com and domain2.com

Using the API I have created group1@masterdomain.onmicrosoft.com, I then changed settings so that domain1.com was the default domain and re-created that group and after a period of time I ended up with group1@domain1.com. I tried again with domain2.com set as default but this time the mail address was group1@masterdomain.onmicrosoft.com

I need to be able to have group1@domain1.com and group1@domain2.com - This is achievable via DirSync. Can anyone provide me guidance on how to replicate this via the API?

Thanks
Steven

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue.  Office 365 seems to randomly assign a domain to your newly created group.

Workaround - After creating the group, issue a PATCH command to change the email to the correct domain:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/contoso.com/groups('c75831bd-fad3-4191-9a66-280a48528679')

Content-Type: application/json

{
    "EmailAddress": "tgr@fusefx.com"
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Get a 503 error with message "The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it."

Comment: Microsoft has since updated to a release version, and this no longer happens.  The PATCH command sometimes had to be delayed to give the system time to retrieve that new record.